# Ruby on Rails Database Association Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have Posts and Categories. I made the associations between both of them, so now I can create a new Post is Posts/new and choose which category I want and display the Posts in Category/1/show. I want to be able to go to Categories/1 and create a new post with that category, without having to choose a category in the form.

Can somebody help me? Thank you.

The models:

Category:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :places
end
```

Place:

```
class Place < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :category  
end
```

in the Place#show i have this link:

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_place_path(@place) %>
```

In the categories_controller:

```
  def show
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])
    @title = @category.name
    @posts = @category.places
  end
```

In the form:

```
  </div>
    <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :category_id %><br>
    <%= f.select :category_id, Category.all.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] }, { include_blank: true } %>
  </div>
```

Comment: What association you define between Post and Category ?

Comment: By `Categories/1` I assume you mean `Categories/:id`, etc. Have you read [Rails ActiveRecord Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)? It describes all of the methods at your disposal that you'd need to do this.

Comment: When you say you "want to be able to go to Categories/1" - what, specifically does that mean? What is the code that would do that? What is the current code for creating a new post?

Answer (score 2):

You should add a new link in `categories#show` view:

```
<%= link_to 'Post to this Category', new_post_path(category_id: @category.id) %>
#=> <a href="posts/new?category_id="2">Post to this Category</a>
```

And then modify your `posts#new` method:

```
def new
  @post = Post.new
  @post.category = Category.find(params[:category_id]) if params[:category_id].present?
end
```

Using this you will have category selected.

Comment: I would actually recommend using the [nested resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#creating-paths-and-urls-from-objects) option instead. The path helper would look like `new_category_post_path(@category)`, and then they can avoid the `@post.category` in the `new` function because the category_id will already be available on the `POST` because it'll automatically be a parameter in the url. This way will work too, but its a bit more verbose, and less "rails"-y.

Comment: I'm trying with nested resources. now I can access categories/30/posts/new but how can I modify the form so it has only the option for the category 30? @PaulRichter